# How do I pass a value through this input field?

Tags: php, html

How do I get the value of what the user inputs into the text field for quantity?

```
echo"<label>Qty:</label><input type=\"text\" name\"qty\" size=\"3\" maxlength=\"3\" value=\"1\"/>";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put some more effort into your question and add some detail. I added what I think are the appropriate tags.

Comment: Where do you need the value? Server or client side?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a form with `method="post"` you will get the value of the field with `$_POST['qty']` (or `$_GET['qty']` for `method="get"` or none) in full:

```
echo "<label>Qty:</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"qty\" size=\"3\" maxlength=\"3\" value=\"".$_POST['qty']."\"/>";
```

but remember to escape **any** data from site users.

Answer (score 0):

in the submitted form for php, it'll look like this:

```
$_REQUEST['qty']
```

in javascript, it'll look like (assuming your form's **id** is "form1")

```
document.getElementById('form1').qty.value
```

or if the **name** is form1

```
document.form1.qty.value
```

If you're using a framework like jQuery:

```
$('#form1 input[name=qty]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an equal sign before you name attribute, and as this is the one you need to get the value with PHP that might be the issue. And you should use single quotes to avoid escaping of every double quote:

```
echo '<label>Qty:</label><input type="text" name="qty" size="3" maxlength="3" value="1" />';
```

On the PHP side you can than get the value through the `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` superglobal:

```
$qty = $_REQUEST['qty'];
```

I hope that was the answer you needed.